# Avoid repetition when navigating pages on PowerBI site with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, powerbi

I'm using Selenium to webscrape a PowerBi site. The data I'm interested is on the fourth page so I've used this code to navigate to it:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"))).click()
```

Is it possible to do the same operation without so much repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to declare variables for the xpath and WebDriverWait:

```
xpath = "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)).click()
```

Otherwise use a loop:

```
xpath = "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

for x in range(1, 3):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)).click()
```

And then wrap it up all neat and tidy with a function:

```
def navigate_to_page(driver, page)
    xpath = "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

    for x in range(1, page):
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)).click()

navigate_to_page(driver, 3)
```

This is just basic python. Nothing special.

Comment: In your function should `for x in range(1, 3):` be `for x in range(1, page):`?

Comment: @runnerpaul: Thanks. We can blame that on the root cause for 90% of my programming mistakes (copy-and-paste).

Comment: Lol no worries. Thanks for the help.